# Why is Duke Nukem Forever loading time so long?

Tags: windows-7, duke-nukem-forever

Does anyone know why is DNF loading time so long?

Is it going to be fixed? (by patch)

Is there now a way to fix it? (without patches)

Windows 7.

Comment: *Duke Nukem Forever* taking a long time to load seems... par for the course.

Comment: *Duke Nukem: Waiting for Forever*.

Comment: I just endend it and I no notice slow ANYTHING. Maybe you could provide your hardware specs...

Answer (score 2):

Check out this [answer](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1928420).

Steps:

- Launch Steam normally, then launch Duke Nukem.
- Press control-alt-del to go to the task manager.
- Right click on Steam to go to process.
- Select Affinity.
- Select only CPU 0. Click OK.
- Set Priority to Low.
- After you're done windows-tab back to the Duke.

Comment: I've had no problem with load times in Windows.  I'm assuming the complaint is probably regarding a console...?

Comment: It was tagged with Windows-7 so i guess not.

Comment: It wasn't tagged that way when I posted that comment.  I'm glad the OP clarified, though!

Comment: Yes. I did not tagged it properly. I apologize for troubles. I will try it ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using full-screen mode, try setting it to windowed instead. The difference this had on my game was astounding.